# Error when replacing div with external html using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a external page 'divone.htm' and I want replace the content of mainbox with content of external page's div #divet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mainbox').load('divone.html #divet');
});
```

However, the content from the file does not load, and I receive the following error in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/.../divone.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource

Comment: What do you mean by _external html_ ? Your code should work

Comment: Could you see some error from console?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/.../divone.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: I've rearranged the text of your question to make it more clear, and added your comment about the error message to the question. This will make it easier for people to know what's wrong with the code  immediately.

Answer (score 2):

In local, Chrome restricts call to local files as if it was from another domain. If divone.html is on same domain as your main page, it will work once on server.

Firefox doesn't have the same restrictions for local content, you can test locally with it.

You can also launch Chrome from command line/terminal and add --allow-file-access-from-files as an argument to remove this restriction. Exact way to call vary depending on your OS.